# How to pass parameters from clientside to PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I didn't get much information on the previous question. So I will give full details about the problem.

On ticket-status.php page code for preview data is:

```
<?php
include('connection.php');
$result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM tickets JOIN users WHERE users.email=tickets.email");
$result->execute();
for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++){
?>
<tr>
<th scope="row"><?php echo $row['ticket_id'] ?></th>
  <td><?php echo $row['item_selected'] ?></td>
 <td><?php echo $row['help_selected'] ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['message'] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['status'] ?></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
```

This is how look users database:

```
ID - FIRST NAME - LAST NAME - EMAIL - PASSWORD - PHONE - CREATED - MODIFIED
1     Greg         McFe       u@g.com   123       123     date      date
2     Roy          McDs       a@g.com   133       222     date      date
3     Tina         MCda       g@g.com   333       111     date      date
```

Database for tickets is:

```
TICKET_ID - ITEM_SELECTED - HELP_SELECTED - EMAIL - PHONE - MESSAGE - STATUS
   1             theme2         problem     u@g.com   123    msg1      open
   2             theme12        errors      a@g.com   222    msg12     open
   3             theme8         solution    g@g.com   333    msg9      closed
```

What i need. On ticket-status.php page when a random user logged in and go to see his ticket status, display his open ticket. Example:

```
TICKET ID - ITEM SELECTED - HELP SELECTED - MESSAGE - STATUS
   2        theme12          errors       msg12       open
```

Comment: Can you also include some sample data, and output, from the tables involved in the join?

Comment: (SELECT * FROM tickets WHERE users.id = tickets.tickets_id) @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: if you mean on that @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: Please add sample data.  Even if someone guesses your answer correctly, the question, in its current form, won't be very helpful to other people in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming email is your link between ticket and user:

```
select * from tickets
join users on users.email=tickets.email
where users.id=123
```

Comment: That is not help me. I need when user ? log in into his profile display only his tickets. See again edited problem.

Comment: How doesn't this do it for you? If you run this query for user 123 then you will see only their tickets. if you want less columns then replace the * with the columns you need.

Comment: Because, when random user log in into his account and go to ticket status page, on that page need to display only his ticket. Same is for other users. @TomC

Comment: Well clearly this was an example for user 123. You need to substitute 123 for whatever your parameter for userid is. If this is a php question "how do I pass a parameter to sql using php" then I'm sorry I can't help you. I have answered the sql part about the sql join which was the subject of this question.

Comment: @mcstudent you might want to ask in another question (or research on the internet) on how to pass parameters from PHP into SQL.

Answer (score 0):

By referring to your comments, it implies that your problem is not about how to perform SQL queries but how to refer to the currently logged in user from **ticket-status.php**
When a user clicks on a button (in the interface) to go the status page, you have to handle that click event in a way such that you can send the information about the current user to **ticket-status.php** to handle it. To get the data from for this you can send them as GET parameters or else POST parameters. Then you get the value passed from the client side like following

If the client side(ex: javascript or ...) sends GET parameters
     `$_GET['id']`

If the client side sends POST parameters
     `$_POST['id']`

For further reference,
https://www.formget.com/php-post-get/

Comment: Data base have 2 tables ( 1. Users 2. Tickets ). When user register that information go to (1.Users) table, when user is registered their able to open ticket for support on ticket-support.php then that post go to (2.tickets) table. When that user go to ticket-status.php that user must be able to see his ticket status. Question is next, how to do that?

Comment: I hope you know about Session variables. when a user is logged in preserve some unique, non-sensitive value(ex: userID) as session variables to identify him in different places.

Comment: I fixed my database tickets and edit code, still have problem with display row into page, but i will fix that soon